# Fail to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile): Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I want to build project and it give error like this:

*Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project messaging-utils-core: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11*

I've tried to fix in various way by Googling it up but it doesn't work in my local. I am using Eclipse.

Here is how my pom.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>sg.com.nets.utils</groupId>
    <artifactId>messaging-utils-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>messaging-utils-core</artifactId>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>sg.com.nets.common.faulttolerance</groupId>
        <artifactId>fault-tolerance-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.solacesystems</groupId>
        <artifactId>sol-jcsmp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.qpid</groupId>
        <artifactId>qpid-jms-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I run mvn --version and it give this:

```
Apache Maven 3.6.3

Java version: 1.8.0_281
```

For my environment I have this:

```
JAVA_HOME = D:\pathlocation\jdk1.8.0_281
```

Please assist me as I try to fix this issue several days already and still haven't solve. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed the issue already. I just add this:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.8.0</version>
<configuration>
    <source>1.8</source> 
    <target>1.8</target>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: this fixed my problem

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to build a project for Java 11 with JDK 8.

So you need to use a newer JDK.

Comment: He is using Java version: 1.8.0_281

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by adding this:

```xml
<properties>
    <java.version>8</java.version>
</properties>
```

In the POM.xml file

Answer (score 0):

In my case:
I had installed java 8 and 17 both on local environment.
but I forgot to update `JAVA_HOME` to JDK 17,
And JAVA IDE was compiling project at `JDK 8` thats why i was getting this error.

once i update `JAVA_HOME` to JDK 17 installed path in environment variables. i was able to resolve this issue.
#jdk8 #jdk17 #springboot2.3 #maven #compilingerrors